# Microsoft Action Pack vs Technet

Tags: licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

I have debated for a couple of years whether or not to purchase [Microsoft's Action Pack](https://partner.microsoft.com/40112699) (took the tests, and currently qualify to purchase it). I am mainly concerned with this question:

Does the Action Pack contain 10 "Full" (not just an upgrade) version of Windows 7 Pro?

The description says "Windows 7 licenses are upgrade licenses only", but a couple people I have talked to said they are able to do clean/full installs, without needing a previous Windows OS installed.

Then the next main question would be, How does Technet subscription compare to the Action Pack when it comes to the above concern regarding Windows 7 licensing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key difference is: how do you intend to use the software from your subscription? If you are planning to use it for actual work, then the Action Pack is your only legal option.

- Action Pack subscriptions provide fully licensed software for your internal use in your business. Note that there are some restrictions on direct revenue-generating activities.
- TechNet subscriptions are for evaluation purposes only. ([detailed list of permitted uses](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/bb892759.aspx))

The Windows 7 "upgrade" licensing is a paperwork requirement only. If you insert a brand new hard drive into a computer with a Windows XP OEM license sticker and run the installation, your Action Pack license key will work fine. You do not need to preinstall an old version of Windows.

Comment: Thank you Miles. You explained it very well... legally, I would more than likely need to purchase the Action Pack. Your explination regaring the XP OEM sticker is exactly what I was looking for, thanks again!

Comment: I'd verify this, and any other MS licensing Q, with Microsoft. My MS rep has explained things differently to me.

Comment: Oh ok Ernie, thanks for the tip - it can be very confusing with licensing.

Comment: Ernie's sentiment is correct: a best-practice community like SF may be able to point you in the right direction, but only Microsoft has the final word on Microsoft licensing.